# How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu Desktop from 10.04 to 10.10 on my netbook.

How can I install Ubuntu Unity for my notebook ?

Comment: Please seperate these questions into different questions

Comment: I've edited your question. Please make a separate question for the Ubuntu One question.

Answer (score 16):

You just need to install the package [ubuntu-netbook](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-netbook).

Answer (score 15):

Search for "Unity Interface for Ubuntu Netbook Edition" in Software Center and install it.

Comment: After installing the unity packages you can start unity by loggin in from GDM and choosing "Ubuntu Netbook Edition" as the desired session.

Comment: I think you should mention that the package is called *unity*.

Answer (score 1):

First question: Ubuntu Unity.
Unity is the default environment on Ubuntu Netbook.  You can download it from here
http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download
The instructions for installation are also there.  If you need clarification, just ask.

Second question: Ubuntu One
Ubuntu One comes standard as part of any recent Ubuntu installation.  You have to sign up for the service before you can access any space online, but any ubuntu or supported derivative (kubuntu, ubuntu netbook, edubuntu, ...) will have the client installed.  In addition to this, an app was developed for the iPhone and for Android so that you can access your files from your mobile (should you have an iPhone or Android.)  Canonical is also working on releasing a Windows version of the Ubuntu one client.  You can get all the details from the ubuntu site (one.ubuntu.com)

Comment: There should actually be no problem in installing Unity on a Desktop Edition installation, as Drulenzie and dvs3500ea indicated in their answers. No need to reinstall to switch to, or simply try out, Unity.

Answer (score -1):

if you go on the ubuntu website click on netbook on the top left you will get detailed instructions.