# Ubuntu Apps to match Apple's OS X Lion?

Tags: mac, apple

I'm writing a post about how the software updates Apple sent out have been on Ubuntu (and other Linux distros) for ages (like the app store and the new "Mission Control" feature) from here: http://www.apple.com/macosx/lion/

I was wondering if i can show that Ubuntu has had apps to match the other two features: Fullscreen apps and "LaunchPad"? Are there?

This would be useful for helping Apple users switch to Ubuntu also when I'm trying to convert them ;)

Comment: Most of these "features" are workarounds to make things work on a phone. I don't see how putting this on a 20" screen should solve anything. But yes, you can autohide a panel, press F11 to fullscreen most "apps" and use multiple screens/compiz to "swipe trough" your programs.

Comment: haha, i *completely* agree.

Comment: ubuntu unity and gnome shell have a similar "Launchpad" menu. You can fullscreen your applications with compiz rules or keybindings (extrawm plugin).

Comment: Ubuntu should be in the business to innovate not duplicate, and since this are new features, they may not even be popular.

Comment: Is there anyway to install just the Unity UI and not install the entire thing as an OS?

Comment: [How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launchpad is basicaly the same as Unity. Mac App Store = Ubuntu Software Center. Full screen apps (as they'll work on Lion) depend on the apps developers. Mission Control is nearly the same as scale compiz plugin, but you can only manage windows.

Comment: Not sure why people gave you a down vote... anyways, thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a way to install Unity as a UI and not an OS?

Comment: Well, Unity, more than an OS is an interface of Ubuntu. There are two interfaces on Ubuntu, the normal Desktop (ubuntu-desktop) and Unity (ubuntu-netbook). You can have both installed on your Ubuntu, if you are using 10.10, simply install "unity" package. On the loging in you could choose Ubuntu Desktop Edition and Ubuntu Netbook Edition, so you won't lose your actual interface.

Comment: Yeah, i was wondering if there was a way to basically switch between the interfaces without having two Ubuntu installs? No?

Comment: Yep, that's what you will exactly have :)