# Unity interface on the Desktop in 11.04

Tags: unity, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition)

The web site omg Ubuntu http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-11-04-to-ship-unity-as-default-desktop/

as omg Ubuntu has confirmed that the unity interface is coming to desktop in version 11.04 because of these recent developments i have decided to change to unity (try to buffer the shock for when i am upgrading)

i believe by entering this into terminal my computer will change to unity'apt-get install ubuntu-netbook' would this be correct?

also if anybody has any proof that omg Ubuntu has their fact wrong please comment.thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition). Yes OMG Ubuntu certainly has the correct news, it was announced by Mark Shuttleworth at the Ubuntu Developer Summit earlier today.

Comment: i will have to adapt to unity :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ubuntu-netbook` package will provide you with the Unity interface, you'll be able to load it from the login screen, selecting a "Netbook Edition" session instead of the "Desktop Edition".

And Unity will ship by default for 11.04, this is correct.