# Is it possible to get the 11.10 Unity Desktop in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition)
>   [Unity interface on the Desktop in 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9398/unity-interface-on-the-desktop-in-11-04)

I am running into severe problems with dual monitors+fglrx in 64bit 11.10, whereas all was good in 11.04.

Is it possible to get the same 11.10 Unity experience in 11.04 (transparency, lens etc etc)?

Comment: What problems are you having with fglrx in 11.10?

Comment: dual screen not working with flgrx (AMD 5870), open sourcxe drivers are way too loud (GPU fan is always on)

Comment: How does configuration file looks like? What kind of configuration are you looking for? (twinview or seperate x?)

Answer (score 2):

No, because they are so different. Even if you did manage to update everything you would get the same problems.