# Upgraded to 10.10 but desktop shell did not change

Tags: unity, upgrade

I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 but my desktop shell did not change to Unity.  How can I change it myself to check it out (and change back if I decide to)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unity is going to be the default in 11.04 (currently unreleased), not 10.10.

To install Unity from within the 10.10 Desktop version [take a look at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition).