# Install netbook remix on maverick meerkat

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, powerpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition)

Hi all,

I've recently decided to give my old [iBook G4](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP43) a new life. As a consequence, after some search, I found [ubuntu  Maverick Meerkat for PowerPC ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/10.10/release/) and installed it. It was fine (although some steps - like correctly configuring network and Airport Extreme - were not that easy, but it's a different story).

So, I've now a working Maverick Meerkat on my iBook.

Besides, I've recently discovered Ubuntu Netbook Remix, and I consider it would be a very cool addition to my iBook and its limited display (1024x768 ... yes, it's that old).

But from what I can see, it seems that UNR ISO is only available for x86 platforms (but I may be wrong, in which case I hope you'll correct me). So is it a way to install it over a "traditionnal" Ubuntu desktop install ? And if so, will it work on PowerPC architecture ?

Thanks

**EDIT** (I let the question open, as it seems to me as a related issue). So, I installed it, and the computer did not complains about it. Unfortunatly, when trying to log in using UNR as desktop (selection done on login screen, when entering the password), I only get a screen telling me to insert the CD (which of course I have not), after what session does not opens, and I go back to login screen. What is the solution to that problem ?