# How to Switch to Netbook Edition

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I am running only one operating system - the latest version of Ubuntu. (I just broke my Windows XP addiction for the first time a few days ago.) But I am having some problems with the size of some windows. My computer is an Acer Aspire One Netbook. So I think it is better for me to switch to the Ubuntu Netbook Edition.

What is the most painless way to do this switch? Do I have to treat this like an entirely new system? Or is there some simpler way for me to swtich/ugrade, especially now that I am already running Ubuntu?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Unity after installing Desktop Edition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5571/how-can-i-install-unity-after-installing-desktop-edition)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Applications -> Software center then install ubuntu-netbook and after installation logout and select Ubuntu Unity Netbook Edition

[image]

Comment: This is the "right" answer, because it is more complete than mine!

Comment: You could consider installing the newer 2D Unity which is more responsive than the current 3D release on 10.10

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alaukik! This indeed seems like the best and simplest solution. I will try it tomorrow. (No time now.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by installing the [ubuntu-netbook](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ubuntu-netbook) package.